# How do I normalise Tensor dataset

Tags: python, pytorch

At first I have a list of lists of lists.

Each pair corresponds to variables x and y. (For instance in the first list of lists we have x=1 y=2, x=1 y=3 x=1 y=4)

```
tensor_input=[[[1,2],[1,3],[1,4]],[[2,5],[0,3],[3,5]]]
```

Now I am transforming it into a numpy array and then into a tensor

```
tensor_input = np.array(tensor_input)
tensor_input = torch.Tensor(tensor_input)
```

I am doing the same operation with tensor_output.

My question is how can I normalise the variables x and y so that I have a normalised input and can then feed it to my neural network with Dataloader. Maybe I should do it by excluding a  variable x from the list of lists to get x=[1,1,1,2,0,3] , same with y=[2,3,4,5,3,5] then normalise it and create a list of lists once again from normalised vectors? Or is there a way to do it easier in pytorch?

```
data_set = TensorDataset(tensor_input, tensor_output)
train, test = torch.utils.data.random_split(data_set, [304, 60])
train_loader = DataLoader(train, batch_size=4, shuffle=True)
```

And a second question as I get the normalised output from the nerual network, how can I retrieve the actual variable?

Answer (score 0):

You could broadcast your input array to `(-1, 2)` then calculate the mean and standard deviation on each component.

```
tensor_input = np.array([[[1,2],[1,3],[1,4]],[[2,5],[0,3],[3,5]]])

x = tensor_input.reshape(-1, 2)
mean = x.mean(axis=0)
std = x.std(axis=0)

x = x - mean
x /= std
x.reshape(tensor_input.shape)
```

This can be done the same with a `torch.tensor`